# What is filling my file system on EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, memory-usage

On my EC2 AMI instance I have an issue that it gets out of memory now and then. And I don't know how to find what is causing it...
 If I do

```
$ sudo df -h
```

I can see that  this takes up all my memory (or 80% in this case since I managed to clean some log files):

```
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  6.4G  1.7G  80% /
```

I would expect

```
sudo find / -type f -size +10M -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

to find other large files, but he size of the files returned with that command is far from 6.4G. Why is that, and how do I do to locate the rest?
Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like these are likely reasons for your stated combination of observations:

- you deleted files that are still open, in such a situation the files are no longer visible in the filesystem but the space cannot be reclaimed until they are closed

  - you may want to look at eg `lsof -n | grep DEL`
- there are a large number of files smaller than what you looked up

  - you may want to look at the overall size of directories in `/` (eg `du -hs /*`) and drill down

Side note: *memory usage* is typically used to refer to RAM usage ("primary memory", if you will), but that is apparently not what this question is about

Comment: For an interactive tool to browse file sizes, and find lots of little files, try  `ncdu -x /`

Comment: Thank you! I did not find the issue yet, but the du -hs /* command seems good. I found out the issue is somewhere in pgsql at least.

Answer (score 0):

Using `du -hs /*` from above answer helped me detect which folder is filling up my disk.

P.S: It was Tomcat `catalina.out` file with 24G :)